# QML equivalent of C# Type "uint"?

Tags: c#, qml

The title is quite clear in my opinion. I got some C# types that I have to log in QML files and I don't know how to manipulate unsigned int...

I'm a pure noob in QML and I found this :
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qtglobal.html#uint-typedef

I'm logging my configurations in a generic object which is "QtObject" but when I got this :

```
QtObject
{
    id: myInt3
    objectName: "myInt3"
    property uint value
}
```

I got a message that my QML file is malformed... and I'm quite sure the problem is the line "property uint value".
I tried "property unsigned int value" but it doesn't work too...
What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to a list of [QML types](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativebasictypes.html). Notice that there is a `int` type but not a `uint` one. The link you provided is for QT types and not QML types.

Comment: It seems like `int` is the way to go.

Comment: Guillaume: Oh, I see. don't specify the type explicitly. Just set the value.

Comment: One potential issue is the loss of range, but that could be checked prior to writing to the QML file.

Answer (score 1):

The type qualifier would be `quint?`, such as `quint16`, `quint32`:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/datastreamformat.html